# Custom Attribute Binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I've got two Silverlight Controls in my project, both have properties TeamId.  I would like to bind these together in XAML in the control hosting both user controls similar to:

```
        <agChat:UserTeams x:Name="oUserTeams" />
        <agChat:OnlineUser x:Name="oOnlineUsers" TeamId="{Binding ElementName=oUserTeams, Path=TeamId}" />
```

In the first control, I'm implementing System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged and raising the PropertyChanged event upon the TeamId property changing.

In the second control, I've used the propdp snippet to identify the TeamId as a Dependency property.

```
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TeamId.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TeamIdProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TeamId", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(OnlineUsers), 
        new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(new System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback(TeamChanged)));
```

However when the silverlight controls first gets created, I get the follow exception from Silverlight:

```
 Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application Invalid attribute value {Binding ElementName=oUserTeams, Path=TeamId} for property TeamId. [Line: 21 Position: 146] at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri xamlUri) at agChat.Page.InitializeComponent() at agChat.Page..ctor() at agChat.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args) at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Obviously this could all be done in code-behind, but this *seems* like the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the correct approach in WPF, but not in Silverlight.

You cannot bind to elements using xaml in Silverlight.

This is the offending line:
 TeamId="{Binding ElementName=oUserTeams, Path=TeamId}"

Specificly ElementName

If you can, place the data object into Resources and declare it there, then you can do this:

```
<agChat:UserTeams x:Name="oUserTeams" 
       DataContext="{StaticResource myDataObject}" />
<agChat:OnlineUser x:Name="oOnlineUsers" 
       DataContext="{StaticResource myDataObject}" 
       TeamId="{Binding  TeamId}" />
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this today. Thanks for the great suggestion! (Looking forward to Element binding support in SL3!)